# user scripts like Greasemonkey are no longer editable in firefox 71 (they were working fine in the 6x version)

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey, userscripts

Just updated to Firefox 71 after not updating for more than an year. Now violentmonkey scripts can't be edited. Then also can't be switched on or off. They were working well in the 6x version of firefox.

Backed up my scripts, then uninstalled and reinstalled, and imported the scripts back. Still same problem.

Uninstalled violentmonkey, installed Greasemonkey. Created a script but it just won't save. Gives the error:

```
Script save error

    User script save failed: script named "Unnamed Script 120573" already exists in namespace "custom_scripts".

The editor contents have not been saved. Fix this error and try again.
```

Whatever I fix, I can't save.

Finally installed a new extension FireMonkey (claims to be using the latest Firefox extension API). Here I am able to save the scripts and a simple

```
alert('hello');
```

works fine. But when I created a script by copy pasting the old violentmonkey script, its not working. (The header was edited to be compliant with FireMonkey).

Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: Same issue for me using a clean install of firefox in a new account and adding nothing but greasemonkey, so seems unlikely to be a configuration issue. There's a [bug open](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/3063)

Comment: debian just released 71.0-2 to fix bugs [#946249](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=946249) and [#946547](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=946547)